# Micrometer Rest API

Tags: spring, micrometer

I have a non boot spring application with micrometer integrated. Right now we are pushing these metrics to the logging file using LoggingRegistry.
We want to enhance this project to expose these metrics in the Rest API(we cannot use actuator as turning ON auto configuration is causing issues in our non boot application).Is there any way to expose these metrics which are automatically provided by the micrometer in the Rest API?
Any example will be appreciated?

Comment: what metrics backend will be consuming the metrics exposed by your REST api?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen It would be splunk and also we are thinking that this API can be used for advanced healh monitoring

Comment: I'm not sure what format splunk expects the metrics to be in but if you are looking for an example, then this class may help. It's used to expose the metrics from the meter registry on an endpoint that prometheus can scrape.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java

Answer (score 0):

You can add `PrometheusMeterRegistry`, it is for this use case, see the docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus

Comment: it wasnt for prometheus.basically needed it to be consumed by internal systems